# Swiftui how to toggle different elements in LazyVStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

If you look at the image below there will be text with a bold **... Read More** and **... Read Less** . The logic is simple if a post has more than 99 characters on startup it'll say **... Read More** and on tap it'll show full post with **... Read Less** .

All of that works however the issue is that if I try to tap on 2 different cells things do not work correctly and I think it's because of this, the ReadMoreState variable is not an array . So it works correctly if it's only 1 cell you click on but not more than 1 .

Here is my code (not all of it only the relevant part) . It is LazyVStack inside a ScrollView any suggestions on how to fix the onTap state of the ReadMoreState variable when it comes to having multiples rows would be great .

To Recap

1. All rows should have ReadMoreState on false when first loading that is working
2. If I tap row 2 then ReadMoreState should be set to true for Row 2 only
3. I know the one of the issues is that ReadMoreState is not an array

   ```
   struct TimeLineView: View {

    @Binding var model: [MainModel]
    @State var ReadMoreState = false
    @State var PostIDState = 0

     var body: some View {
       ZStack
         {
         Color(UIColor.white)
            .ignoresSafeArea()

        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack {

                ForEach(model) { value in

                 if value.post.count >= 99 {
                   PostToggle(value.post,State: ReadMoreState,ID: PostIDState, Tapped:   ReadMoreState,PostID: value.id!)
                                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        ReadMoreState.toggle()
                                        PostIDState = value.id!
                                    }

                               }
         }
       }
     }.listRowInsets(.none)

    .onAppear(){

        MainViewModel().MainViewRequest(type: "All") { data in
            self.model = data!

        }
     }
    }
    }



     func PostToggle(_ post: String, State: Bool,ID: Int, Tapped: Bool,PostID: Int) -> Text
     {

    if ID == 0 && State == false  {

        return Text(post.prefix(80)) + Text(" ... Read More").bold()
    }

    else if  ID != 0 && PostID == ID && State == true {
       return Text(post) + Text(" ... Read Less").bold()
    } else   {
        return Text(post.prefix(80)) + Text(" ... Read More").bold()
    }

   }
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using one `@State` for multiple items in a `ForEach`. The simplest way is to outsource that View in another View. That view contains a @State for showing more. Hence, you have a @State for every view. Here is demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var text : [String] = ["Test jahd jkahsj kdhsaj khdahf jhsd alkjf hak sdljhf akljshf klshdf kljshjf ahsdhfhsk hfjs dhkj fshfkj hjkfhdsjkf hasfdsaa", "ajdhj kfhaj dshf jkd shf jkh dsj hasjf hdj", "Without more text"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(text, id:\.self) { value in
                    TextLayerView(text: value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TextLayerView : View {
    @State var showMore : Bool = false
    var text : String
    
    var body : some View {
        if(text.count > 20 && !showMore) {
            VStack {
                Text(text.prefix(20))
                Button(action: {
                    //
                    showMore.toggle()
                })
                {
                    Text("Show more")
                }
            }
        }
        else if showMore {
            Text(text)
            Button(action: {
                showMore.toggle()
            })
            {
                Text("Show less")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```